# Can not set value as dropdown selected value using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one issue.when i am fetching values from database and try to set those values on html view using angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

My controller file contains the following code.

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "php/homeuserrole/editRoleData.php",
            data:userdata,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
                //console.log('edited data',response.data[0].user_role);
                $scope.user_role=response.data[0].user_role;
                $scope.user_name.value=response.data[0].user_name;
                $scope.buttonName="Update";

        },function errorCallback(response) {
        });
```

Inside the success function i am binding the values to following html view.

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">User Name :</span>
<select id="coy" name="coy" class="form-control" ng-model="user_name"  ng-options="user.name for user in listOfName track by user.value" >
<!--<option value="">Select course</option>-->
</select>
</div> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <!--<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Login Name :</span>
<input type="text" name="itemname" id="contactno" class="form-control" placeholder="add Login Name" ng-model="login_name" >
</div>-->
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">User Role :</span>
<select id="coy" name="coy" class="form-control" ng-model="user_role" >
<option value="">Select User Role</option>
<option value="Princpal">Princpal</option>
<option value="HOD">HOD</option>
<option value="Lab Assistance">Lab Assistance</option>
<option value="Professor ">Professor</option>
<option value="Ast.Professor ">Ast.Professor</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Here i am able to set value in first dropdown list(`i.e-user name`) but the value can not be set at second dropdown list(`i.e-user Role`).it is showing blank when that success function is executing.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need to also mention ng-options in the second dropdown too. Similar like this -

```
ng-options="user.name for user in listOfName track by user.value"
```